# Combining Data from Two Pandas Dataframes After Using to_list to Create Second Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine the results of two dataframes containing data from an API.

I have this dataframe called football_league_df:

| Competition | Comp_ID |
| --- | --- |
| English Northern Premier League | 12200889 |
| Northern Irish Premiership | 12199359 |
| UAE U21 | 6193239 |

I convert the Comp_ID column to a list using:

```
football_league_list = football_league_df['Comp_ID'].tolist()
```

Then create another dataframe called upcoming_events_df using:

```
event_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(competition_ids=football_league_list)
upcoming_events = trading.betting.list_events(
    filter=event_filter
```

| Event Name | Event_ID |
| --- | --- |
| CFR Cluj v ACS Sepsi OSK | 31805926 |
| Neuchatel Xamax v Schaffhausen | 31826401 |
| Thun v Yverdon Sport | 31826402 |
| Wales v England | 31769069 |

I want to create a third dataframe that contains all the data and columns in the second dataframe but also includes a column containing the applicable Competition from the first dataframe.

The Competition data is not available in the same API call so how do I get the desired output? Example below:

| Event Name | Event_ID | Comp_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CFR Cluj v ACS Sepsi OSK | 31805926 | 12200889 |
| Neuchatel Xamax v Schaffhausen | 31826401 | 12199359 |
| Thun v Yverdon Sport | 31826402 | 6193239 |
| Wales v England | 31769069 | 6193239 |

Comment: This should do what you're after: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html